# What would be a descriptive name for this UI element?

Tags: terminology, games, options

I'm looking for a descriptive and relatively intuitive name for this UI element you very often find in game's settings screens. It's a list of options (labels) that you can horizontally run through and that usually convey a "from lower to higher" or "from worse to better" feeling when going from left to right.

[image: UI Element]

Comment: Maybe 'Horizontal Option Roller'

Comment: To observe: its working as if it were a physical wheel of a 'power' controller: like a 1-10 volume button on an amp.  However I don't know of a UX name for the physical control ( technically they are 'pots' - potentiometers )

Answer (score 2):

Often this pattern is used to input numbers in this case this would be an "input stepper". This would fit to this element to since the name does not imply that only numbers can be selected. So I would go with something like the following:

- Input stepper
- Option stepper

Comment: Good call on 'Stepper'.  https://www.nngroup.com/articles/input-steppers/  So maybe Horizontal Stepper ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of Googling using terms such as `Horizontal Selector`, `Horizontal Picker`, `Horizontal Carousel` etc. leads to the realization that this UI element is simply a...

**Single-element carousel**

> [image: single-element carousel]
> [Image source](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php) and [Carousel Demo](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel)

.. albeit with a few changes: no sliding animation, no looping, and no carousel slide marker

---

The UI element seems to take other forms as well:

**Number pickers with horizontal scroll view**

> [image: number picker 1]
> [Image source](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker/issues/94) and [Android Library](https://jitpack.io/p/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker)
>
> [image: number picker 2]
> [Image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252810/how-do-you-make-a-horizontal-number-picker-widget-in-flutter)
>
> [image: number picker 3]
> [Horizontal Number Picker – Concept](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/161003755409307117/)
>
> [image: number picker 4]
> [Image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357512/custom-horizontal-scroll-view-with-picker)

**Spinner/Dial Picker (iOS)**

> [image: dial picker]

**Timeline Datepicker**

> [image: timeline datepicker]
> [Image source](https://github.com/101Loop/DatePickerTimeline)

**RecyclerView (Android)**

> [image: recyclerview]
> [Source](https://youtu.be/XJkCtm4qdwU)